# Unity moving text when player hit object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have score text on the scene, so when player hit a object, it need to show value of points which are moving from botton to up of the screenplay. When player hit object, value of points are shown but it's not moving up. It's fixed.

This is line of code which I tried to apply, but doesen't work

```
hitPrefab.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(1f, y+1, 0f);
```

Any solutions?
Thanks and kind regards

Comment: To better help you, include all the relevant code.

Comment: I suggest you make an animation for your text then you can have better visuality. Search on web there are tutorials for this subject.

Answer (score 0):

Use `transform.position`:

```
hitPrefab.transform.position = new Vector3 (1f, y+1f, 0f);
```

where `y` is `hitPrefab.transform.position.y`.

Comment: Dosen't work my friend. Now, I can't see text about points. And dosen't move. It's fixed. I need show and move from bottom do upper of screen.

Comment: Could you show the code of that class, to have a better idea in how can we help you